# unable to install (sudo apt --fix-broken install)

Tags: package-management, mysql

```
$sudo apt --fix-broken install

    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    Correcting dependencies... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      galera-3 libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbd-mysql-perl libdbi-perl libjemalloc1
      libmysqlclient20 libreadline5 libterm-readkey-perl mariadb-common socat
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      mysql-server-5.7
    Suggested packages:
      mailx tinyca
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      mysql-server-5.7
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 313 not upgraded.
    2 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/3,196 kB of archives.
    After this operation, 48.3 MB of additional disk space will be used.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
    Preconfiguring packages ...
    (Reading database ... 192089 files and directories currently installed.)
    Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb ...
    Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
    invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
    invoke-rc.d returned 5
    There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
    Stop it yourself and try again!
    dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb (--unpack):
     new mysql-server-5.7 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that downloaded deb-archive was corrupted.

Remove it with

```
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-5.7_5.7.25-0ubuntu0.18.04.2_amd64.deb
```

and retry with

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```